# Define input parameter of type struct

Tags: ios, objective-c, struct

In the below code I am trying to define a struct and define an input parameter to the method mentioned in the code below.
I defined the struct as shown below in the code however define input parameter of type struct is a bit unclear to me.

Please let men know how to achieve it.

**code**

```
@interface PlaceView : NSObject {
   struct adheranceType {
      NSUInteger *FIT_SEAMLESS;
      NSUInteger *LOOSE_WITH_GAP;
      NSUInteger *TIGHT_OVERLAP;
   } *type;
}

+ (float) placeViews:(NSArray *)uiviews;
+ (float) placeViews:(NSArray *)uiviews WithAdereanceType: () adheranceType;

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
   typedef struct adheranceType {
      NSUInteger FIT_SEAMLESS;
      NSUInteger LOOSE_WITH_GAP;
      NSUInteger TIGHT_OVERLAP;
   } adheranceType;
```

Then:

```
+ (float) placeViews:(NSArray *)uiviews;
+ (float) placeViews:(NSArray *)uiviews WithAdereanceType: (adheranceType) adheranceType;
```

That will compile, but still almost everything about your code will be wrong. You probably want an enum here.

Comment: would you please provide example for it with enum. i tried it but it does not work. also i am newbie in obj-c